# How to get the same view output of text that i should enter in my text box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am typing some text in my textbox like below format....:-

eg...
(hi i am xyz.

i work in a company which is product based.

and i work as a software engineer.)

after typing above text however i am pressing submit i am getting the below result in my view:-

(hi i am xyz.i work in a company which is product based.and i work as a software engineer.)

I am not getting how to get the display same as i have written in the textbox.

I will be highly thankful if someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside a pre tag.

```
<pre><%= @variable_name %></pre>
```

Or try simple_format

```
<%= simple_format(@variable_name) %>
```

Comment: As you're new here, please don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper:

```
my_text = "Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break."

simple_format(my_text)
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"
```

You can also add the option to warp it with specific tags or perform sanitization.